# How to render different component onClick using React material-ui Drawer list?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I am working on Dashboard design using **React material-ui** package. I have an App bar and a Drawer with a List of different items. When I click items in Drawer, I want to render the respective component inside the "**main**" tag of Drawer.

The App.js component is class-based. And I have functional component for all other routes and features.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useAuthState } from '../contexts/AuthContext';
import InboxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox';
import DraftsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Drafts';

import {MenuItem, MenuList, ListItemIcon, ListItemText
        , Drawer, ListItem, List, Divider, CssBaseline
        , Paper, IconButton, Typography, AppBar, Toolbar
        , Button, Input } from '@material-ui/core';

const drawerWidth = 200;

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
      display: 'flex',
    },
    appBar: {
        width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
        marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    },
    menuButton: {
      marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
      fontSize: "16px",
      color: "#fff",
    },
    hide: {
        display: 'none',
    },
    drawer: {
        width: drawerWidth,
        flexShrink: 0,
    },
    drawerPaper: {
        width: drawerWidth,
    },
    toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,

    content: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
        padding: theme.spacing(3),
    },

    title: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        fontSize: "18px",
    },
    LinkBar: {

    },
    SideBarFont: {
        fontSize: "14px",
    },
}));


export default function Dashboard(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const theme = useTheme();
    const { setUser } = useAuthState();
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <AppBar 
                className={classes.appBar}
                position="fixed"
            >
                <Toolbar>
                    <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title} noWrap>
                        Dashboard
                    </Typography>

                    <Button color="inherit">Logout</Button>

                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>

            <Drawer
                className={classes.drawer}
                variant="permanent"
                anchor="left"
                classes={{
                    paper: classes.drawerPaper,
                }}
                >
                <div className={classes.toolbar} />
                <Divider />

                <List component="nav" aria-label="main mailbox folders">
                    <ListItem button>
                        <ListItemIcon>
                            <InboxIcon />
                        </ListItemIcon>

                        <ListItemText disableTypography className={classes.SideBarFont} primary="User" />
                    </ListItem>
                    <ListItem button>
                        <ListItemIcon>
                            <DraftsIcon />
                        </ListItemIcon>

                        <ListItemText disableTypography className={classes.SideBarFont}  primary="Account" />
                    </ListItem>

                    <ListItem button>
                        <ListItemIcon>
                            <DraftsIcon />
                        </ListItemIcon>

                        <ListItemText disableTypography className={classes.SideBarFont}  primary="Customer Support" />
                    </ListItem>

                    <ListItem component={Link} to="/inventory" button>
                        <ListItemIcon>
                            <DraftsIcon />
                        </ListItemIcon>

                        <ListItemText disableTypography className={classes.SideBarFont}  primary="Inventory" />
                    </ListItem>
                </List>

            </Drawer>

            <main className={classes.content}>
                <div className={classes.toolbar} />
                <h1>Hello</h1>
                <Typography paragraph>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum
                </Typography>

            </main>           

        </div>
    );
}
```

I have functional components for Users, Inventory, CustomerSupport, Account in their respective jsx files. How can i render  or  inside "**main**" when the user click on Drawer List items?

See below for the UI. I want to render where Hello is rendered.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you'll need to do a few things.

1. Create components to render in the `main`
2. Import those components into the `Dashboard` Component

Since you are already using `useState` in your components, you'll need to set up another `useState`.

On your `ListItem` you can add an `onClick` to the component and do the `useState` function to set that state to a said component.

In the `main` you'll need to add some sort of ternary or checker to determine what component to display.

I have removed a number of items here but this is a brief example for you:

```
import User from '/path/to/user/component';
import Account from '/path/to/account/component';
...
export default function Dashboard(props) {
  const [component, setComponent] = useState('user')
  ...
  return (
    ...
    <ListItem button onClick={() => setComponent('account')}>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <DraftsIcon />
      </ListItemIcon>

      <ListItemText disableTypography className={classes.SideBarFont} primary="Account" />
    </ListItem >
    ...

      <main className={classes.content}>
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        {
          component === 'user' ?
          <User />
          :
          component === 'account' ?
          :
          <Account />
          ...
        }
      </main>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Yes there is a cleaner way to do the component rendering in the `main` but this should give you an idea of where to start

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the reply. I changed the code based on your suggestion: <ListItem onClick={setComponent('user')} button>
                        <ListItemIcon>
                            <InboxIcon />
                        </ListItemIcon>
                        
                        <ListItemText disableTypography className={classes.SideBarFont} primary="User" />
                    </ListItem>. But is is throwing an error of Too-many re-renders on the line of serComponent('user')

Comment: @dhavalnc1 sorry I just made an edit, the click is going to fire a ton of times after I looked over it, change it to `onClick={() => setComponent('user')}` so that it only fires once

Comment: Awesome. It works now with the change. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The above suggestions work perfectly. Now, is there any way I can add/make a new dynamic route when I render a different component? For example, when the user clicks on Account in the left sidebar, I want to display URL like "www.abc.com/accounts". I know that we can declare Routes using <Route path.. render..>. But the problem is my Routes will be dynamic based on the JSON response after login. I can not define a static route. I don't know if i am missing a core knowledge of react-router. What should i search in google to find answer to this uestion?

Comment: @dhavalnc1 I would suggest a search like `React Material UI Drawer Router` it would return things like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50801093/material-ui-drawer-selection-how-to-route
and other youtube tutorials that you could follow as well