# How to use React Router with Material UI Drawer to change content on click?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, navigation-drawer, single-page-application

I've tried using Component={Link} to={path} but that just changes the URL.
The content is displayed inside main and I've used Routes inside there like so:

```
<main>
  <Switch>
    <Route path={..} component={..}>
    .
    .
    .
  </Switch>
</main
```

But this doesn't work, the content doesn't change

Link to material UI example: https://codesandbox.io/s/v66pl

Comment: Do you mean to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57223230/how-to-render-different-component-onclick-using-react-material-ui-drawer-list

Comment: @Oleg this is what I'm doing right now, but I don't think it's a good way plus it causes page to refresh right? I'd like it to do it via routes, not by manipulating state and conditional rendering

Comment: Look at very similar sample with tabs: https://codesandbox.io/s/l4yo482pll

Comment: @Oleg that's what I mentioned in the question description, that doesn't work. Could you try implementing it on the material UI codesandbox example?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Added to your sample as you requested: `BrowserRouter`, `Link`.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-605w9

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Turns out the problem was I was importing Switch and Route from react-router-dom/umd instead of react-router-dom